# Como puedo eliminar un elemento de una lista con jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

### bueno soy novato en esto de la programación espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo una lista a la cual le tengo que añadir elementos y borrarlos, el primer botón añade un ítem, el segundo borra el primer ítem,el tercero borra el ultimo ítem y el ultimo botón me tiene que pedir que ingrese un valor y este sea borrado de la lista ej.(me pida borrar el elemento 0 y se borre el "item 1" o el elemento 2 y se borre el "ítem 3") Por favor ayúdenme con este ultimo no entiendo como poder hacerlo gracias de antemano.

---

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Practica</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="adicionar()"> Adicionar Un Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminarprimero()"> Eliminar Primer Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminarultimo()"> Eliminar Ultimo Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminaritem()"> Eliminar Un Item</button>

<ul>

    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

</body>

<script src="js/todo.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</html>


----------


$("li")

function adicionar()
{
    var valor= prompt("Ingrese un valor para el item");
    $("ul").append('<li>' + valor+ '</li>');


}

function eliminarprimero(){
    $("li:first").remove();
}

function eliminarultimo(){
    $("li:last").remove();
}

function eliminaritem(){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `:eq()` debes poner el numero de lista que deseas en los paréntesis, recuerda que se empieza a contar desde 0, [mas información](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```js
function adicionar() {
  var valor = prompt("Ingrese un valor para el item");
  $("ul").append('<li>' + valor + '</li>');
}

function eliminarprimero() {
  $("li:first").remove();
}

function eliminarultimo() {
  $("li:last").remove();
}

function eliminaritem() {
  var valor = prompt("Ingrese elvalor del item a eliminar");
  $("li:eq(" + valor + ")").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="adicionar()"> Adicionar Un Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminarprimero()"> Eliminar Primer Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminarultimo()"> Eliminar Ultimo Item</button>
<button type="button" onclick="eliminaritem()"> Eliminar Un Item</button>

<ul id="listaa">

  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, no tenia idea de como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

En el selector tienes que indicar el elemento de la lista que quieres borrar.
Prueba implementando el método de la siguiente forma:

```
function eliminaritem(){
    var valor = prompt("Ingrese la posición del item a borrar");
    $('ul li:eq(' + valor + ')').remove();
}
```

Comment: **muchas gracias**